# How to define a non continuous range in COUNTIF

Tags: excel, formula

```
   A    B   C

1  Β        Β
2  Β        Β
3  Α        Α
4  Α        Α
5  Β        Β
6  Α        Α
7  Α        B
8  Β        Β
9  Β        Β
10 Α        Α
11 Β        A
12 Α        Α
13 Α        Α
14 Β        Β
15 Α        Α
16 Β    ??
```

In cell B16 I want to count how many "B"s (the value in A16) are in cells C1:C15 *and* A16. Then using some function I will put an "A" or "B" in cell C16. How can I give such a range in COUNTIF? The same formula must be used for every cell in column B.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's the formula for cell B16:
`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C1:C15","A16"}),"B"))`

Comment: nice one - I didn't know you could use `{ }` within an `INDIRECT` to declare non continuous ranges

Comment: You can use ``INDIRECT`` to create an array of ranges, but you can only pass it strings. Therefore you need to manually update the ranges for each cell. Alternatively, you could write a VBA function to do this.

Answer (score 19):

As an alternative that would work for copying and pasting, you could do:

```
=COUNTIF($C$1:$C$15,"B") + COUNTIF(A16,"B")
```

Comment: While my answer might be a vehicle to introduce people to the `INDIRECT` function, this answer is beautifully simple.

Comment: While a bit cumbersome for many discontinuous cells it has the huge advantage of adjusting cells automatically if rows or columns are deleted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, if I understand well, you want to count the value from the cell `A16`. But if you do such a formula:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C15,A16)
```

You **know** you will have the value (here `B`) in cell `A16`, don't you?

So the value you want to get is:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C15,A16) + 1
```

What did I misunderstand?

Comment: No, I don't. It can be either an A or B. So I can't use "+1"

Comment: Not if you are using a var (`A16` in this case) in your formula

Comment: Ok , I should have said that actually I want a formula to calculate abs(alphas-betas)

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare a named range of non-contiguous ranges, but you must use the INDIRECT function in declaring the range.  Otherwise, it will fail just like a normal, non-contiguous range.

Declaring the range ("Range1") should have the "applies to" field read:

```
=INDIRECT({"A1:B2","C4:F17"})
```

Or use other named ranges:

```
=INDIRECT({"Table1[Column1]","Table2[Column3]","Table4[Column2]")
```

Then you can reference it like:

```
=COUNTIF(Range1,"=Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

This also worked!  =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"J18","J45","J78","J112","J140","J173","J205"}),">1"))