# Setting a countif range

Tags: excel, function, if-statement

just wondering, doing a count if statement and there is a thing that asks for range parameter. (range, value). is there anyway i can do like a range A3-A8 but also include A1, not A2. 
Like an A1::A3:A8. Is there a syntax for this?

THanks in advance

Comment: I think this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421139/how-to-define-a-non-continuous-range-in-countif

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that within COUNTIF, you only have the option to specify a single range. Some other functions allow you to specifiy multiple ranges/references, e.g. SUM, AVERAGE, SUBTOTAL and others, e.g.

`=SUM(A1,A3:A8)`

.....but with COUNTIF I think you need two COUNTIF functions like

`=COUNTIF(A1,"x")+COUNTIF(A3:A8,"x")`

or as the first COUNTIF is just a single cell in that case you can use a simpler expression, i.e.

`=(A1="x")+COUNTIF(A3:A8,"x")`

Comment: *Internet pat on the back* Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A1,"myCriteria")+COUNTIF(A3:A8,"myCriteria")`