# Excel INDIRECT() with non-contiguous range ... only works with COUNTIF()?

Tags: excel

I need to use the Excel Indirect() function to reference a non-contiguous range.   This ([How to define a non continuous range in COUNTIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421139/how-to-define-a-non-continuous-range-in-countif)) answer gives an example.

In summary, the OP has two ranges, C1:C15 and A16. Each range contains either an A or a B, and the way to count the number of B's across these two ranges is

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C1:C15","A16"}),"B"))
```

If I change all the B's to 1's and the A's to 0's, and change this formula slightly to

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C1:C15","A16"}),"1"))
```

Then this still works ... BUT! this doesn't:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT({"C1:C15","A16"}))
```

I can work around this, but am I missing something fundamentally magic about the COUNTIF() function, that somehow influences the INDIRECT() function to behave as expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a non continuous range in COUNTIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421139/how-to-define-a-non-continuous-range-in-countif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use a non-contiguous range in `COUNTIF`.

What's actually happening with the first formula is that `COUNTIF` is being fed with an array of (two) separate ranges and therefore the result is an array of the results of two counts, then `SUM` is used to sum the array.

If you actually have 1s and zeroes wouldn't you just SUM them with this formula

`=SUM(C1:C15,A16)`

If you are just trying to find why your last formula doesn't work then, yes, I think `COUNTIF` does work differently - it's able to handle an array of ranges while some other functions can't. This is common to the "IFS" family of functions, so `SUMIF`, for example, can do the same