# Non-consecutive range in excel function

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table were `A1 = "YES"`, `B1 = "YES"` and `C1 = "YES"`. I want to know how many "YES" are in my table, which is easily solved with `=COUNTIF(A1:C1,"YES")` and it will accurately give me the answer of 3.

```
   A    B    C   
1 YES  YES  YES
```

But if want to know how many "YES" are in A1 and C1 and ignore whatever B1 has it becomes tricky. The same function gives me 3 while I want it to give me 2 as an answer since I want to count only A1 and C1.

I want to know if there is a way to manage data so I can work only with that kind of non-consecutive cells? I found that a solution would be using something like `=if(A1="YES",1)+if(C1="YES",1)` and it works like a charm since it will always give me the right answer; however, that is not a satisfying solution because despite the simplicity in my example, my real situation requires to write around 100 cells from a 500 range for several different combinations which can become somewhat heavy.

I tried using name ranges but it seems the if functions doesn't let me use them the way I want. So any help will be apreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, Functions like COUNTIF have limits, like everything, if its column based why not `COUNTIF` at the bottom of each column you want to include and then sum the totals?

Comment: `CountIf` appears to [not support non-consecutive ranges](http://superuser.com/a/447560/52365).

Comment: Is there a pattern to the column stagger? `MOD(COLUMN(), x)` where x identifies the stagger can be used. Need more information than "around 100 cells from a 500 range".

Comment: Is there ANY pattern to the location of the cells you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

If VBA is an option and "non-consecutive ranges in excel functions" is the question, then you could create a `User Defined Function` which takes a `ParamArray` and returns an array out of all given parameters.

Example

```
Public Function getMatrix(ParamArray aValues() As Variant) As Variant
 Dim i As Long
 Dim aReturnValues() As Variant
 For Each vValue In aValues
  For Each vSingleValue In vValue ' possible the vValue is also an array
   ReDim Preserve aReturnValues(i)
   aReturnValues(i) = vSingleValue
   i = i + 1
  Next
 Next
 getMatrix = aReturnValues
End Function
```

This could then be used like:

[image]

Formula in `A4`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(getMatrix(A1,C1,E1:G1,D2:E3)="Yes"))
```

Note, the `UDF` is returning an array, not a `Range`. Thats why we cannot use `COUNTIF`. `COUNTIF` needs a `Range` as first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why looking for a formula when you have other features in Excel? Add a row (#2), and have A2=1, B2=0, C2=1 till the last column [Drag it to populate, Make sure to Copy Cells]. Then select row and see the Sum in Status Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421139/how-to-define-a-non-continuous-range-in-countif) thread. Basically what you need is something like this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A1:A10","C1:c10"}),"a"))
```

Or just use multiple COUNTIFs, and add them. (Countif(...) + countif(...) etc.)