# What function do the {} brackets serve in an Excel formula?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

As the question suggests, I'm wondering what the {} do inside of an Excel formula.

PLEASE NOTE: I am NOT referring to the condition in which the formula is wrapped in {} (i.e. {=SUM(IF(A1:A6>5,1))}). I understand this is an array formula, am familiar with how they function, and am even quite fond of them.

I am asking this question because, in an attempt to find a solution to a somewhat niche issue I was having, I stumbled across this post: [How to define a non continuous range in COUNTIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421139/how-to-define-a-non-continuous-range-in-countif)
In it, the solution recommended for the issue posted was:
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"C1:C15","A16"}),"B"))

Using my understanding of arrays, I surmised that the solutions were creating an array of strings and forcing the formula to function similarly to a standard array formula. But when trying to alter this formula by replacing one of the hardcoded range address strings with a function that results in a string, such as CONCATENATE(), it breaks. The formula won't recognize the ranges within the CONCAT or any other function, and so the function itself gives an error and disallows me from hitting enter to keep changes made to the formula. It appears the {}'s are a very niche syntactical component of functions that take in a single string parameter, such as INDIRECT(), but I don't know if that's just my lack of knowledge of them outside of array formulas and my inability to find anything about them without wading through a sea of array formula search results.

So my question would be what, exactly, is the syntax these interior {}'s should be used in, or require? Do they only function as a replacer for a string value, and/or can only contain strings?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Comment: The name of the feature is [array constant](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-array-constants-in-array-formulas-477443ea-5e71-4242-877d-fcae47454eb8), and yes, it has to be a constant (as opposed to a function result). It is unhelpfully not mentioned on that page, but it is mentioned in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/name-an-array-constant-69431fa5-9bed-4612-950b-25e898b265f5.

Comment: Okay, I thought it was a constant, but I was hoping otherwise. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction for documentation regarding that feature!