# How to combine multiple COUNTIF formula in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm creating a test summary sheet collecting data from multiple tabs in a single spreadsheet using `COUNTIF`-formula, eg:

```
=COUNTIF(OSPF!H3,"PASS")+COUNTIF(OSPF!H8,"PASS")+COUNTIF(OSPF!H13,"PASS").
```

Here data is collected from different cells(not continuous cellrange). Problem is, if the testcases list is big, then the `COUNTIF`-formula also will be large. Is there any option to simplify this formula.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your data. What is with the cells in between? Can "PASS" occur there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Actually I'm taking the data from the random cells.I can explain in detail if i can attach the excel sheet here,But I'm not sure how to attach the sheet here.

Comment: I just want to know, what the other cells around contain. If they will never contain "PASS", you could just use `countif` over the whole range. Just make a screenshot of a part of your data, if it is ok to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
One way to simplify it is to use just one `COUNTIF` function and combine all the cells into one noncontinguous range. With some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422604/1089416), I came up with the following for your case:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"OSPF!H3","OSPF!H8","OSPF!H13"}),"PASS"))
```

**Option 2**
If you have control over what appears in each cell ("PASS"), then you could easily change "PASS" to "1" (if passing) or "0" (if failing). Then no `COUNTIF` would be necessary, just a simple `SUM` of all those cells instead.

**Option 3**
A variation of Option 2 would be to use a helper cell next to the cell that contains "PASS", which does the `COUNTIF` just for that single cell. Then in the "master" sheet, you just sum the helper cells that contain integers.

Comment: Thank you very much Neizan. I tried Option 1 and it worked fine for me.